# relating two diagrams in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

minimal working example is

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date TeX systems
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % do you *really* need it?
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rr] &  & B \arrow[dd] &  & C \arrow[dd] \arrow[rr] &  & D \arrow[dd] \\
&  &  \arrow[rr]   &  &                                                       &  &\\ 
E \arrow[rr]  &  & F             &  & G \arrow[rr]                                          &  & H                       
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

From this minimal example, I expected two squares and an arrow pointing from one square to another square. It is showing error:

**Package pgf Error: No shape named tikz@f@7-2-5 is known. I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 2-3.
Package pgf Error: No shape named tikz@f@7-2-5 is known. I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 2-3.
It is better to use one of the extsizes classes, if you can.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create the arrow between arrows, just add empty labels, they create nodes you can later refer to draw the arrow, see [package documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) at Section *2.3 Absolute placement of arrows*.

Moreover, you don't need to add empty rows and columns to increase the row/column sep, there are appropriate options: `row sep=..., column sep=...`.

*Edit:* to add an implication arrow as in `$\Rightarrow$`, just add `Rightarrow` option, see package documentation at Section *1.3 Changing arrow tips*.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date TeX systems
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % do you *really* need it?
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2cm, column sep=2cm]
A \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & B \arrow[d,""{name=BF}] &  C \arrow[d,""{name=CD, left}] \arrow[r] &  D \arrow[d] \\
E \arrow[r]  &  F &  G \arrow[r]  &  H 
\arrow[from=BF,to=CD, Rightarrow]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You're welcome and thank you for accepting my answer! You can find it in the package documentation at Section *1.3 Changing arrow tips*.

Answer (score 5):

You only need to ad invisible characters to cell in the middle row before arrow and in cell after arrow:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % do you *really* need it?
%\usepackage{datetime}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1cm, column sep=2cm]
A \ar[dd]\ar[r] & B \ar[dd] & C \ar[dd] \ar[r]  & D \ar[dd] \\
    & ~\ar[r,Rightarrow]    & ~                 &           \\
E \ar[r]        & F         & G \ar[r]          &  H    
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]